# cannot find symbol import com.user.userCom

Tags: java, android, react-native

Trying to create native module for react-native.  I have all the dependencies needed and I followed the instructions [user com mobile sdk installation](https://user.com/en/mobile-sdk/installation/)

in `project/android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        …
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.user.com'
        }
    }
}
```

in `project/android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.user:android-sdk:1.0.0'
}
```

then i created file in `project/app/src/main/java/com/my_app/UserComModule.java`

```
package com.my_app;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.user.UserCom;

public class UserComModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

      @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    new UserCom.Builder(
            this,
            "api_secret", //your api secret key generated in User.com webpanel details
            "https://<your_app_subdomain>.user.com"
    )
            .trackAllActivities(true)  // false by default
            .openLinksInChromeCustomTabs(true) // true by default
            .setCustomTabsBuilder(getCustomTabsBuilder())
            .build();
    }

}
```

When i run i get: `cannot find symbol import com.user.UserCom;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing UserCom, and that module is not availabe, as you've mentioned you had created the file UserComModule in that directory, either create UserCom class or delete this line from UserComModule

> import com.user.UserCom;

Comment: i updated my question. In instruction shows there is method calling  `new UserCom.Builder(` if i removed import line get error package UserCom doest not exists

Comment: okay, can you specify the exact error, is it cannot find symbol import com.user.UserCom, or cannot find com.user.UserCom or UserCom

Comment: cannot find symbol import com.user.UserCom and in description `symbol: class UserCom, location: package com.user`

Comment: @Sam replace that line that, import com.user.sdk.UserCom;